# What were the effects of US foreign policy in the South East Asian region in the 1950s, 1960s and 1970s on states with capitalist economies?

Tags: communism, asia

US foreign policy in South East Asia in the 1950s, 1960s and 1970s was ostensibly anti-communist.  It involved civil and military action in a wide number of countries in this region.

Most notably, in connection with the Domino theory, the United States tried to prevent the spread of political and economic change by civil and military action towards Soviet-style politics and economics.

In the opinions of some participants, this action gave breathing space for existing capitalist states to solidify their power. For example, here's a [quote](http://www.pressrun.net/weblog/2009/07/lee-kuan-yew-mcnamara-and-the-vietnam-war.html) by modern Singapore's Founding Father, [Lee Kuan Yew](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lee_Kuan_Yew):

> Although American intervention failed in Vietnam, it bought time for
>   the rest of Southeast Asia. In 1965, when the US military moved
>   massively into South Vietnam, Thailand, Malaysia and the Philippines
>   faced internal threats from armed communist insurgents and the
>   communist underground was still active in Singapore. Indonesia, in the
>   throes of a failed communist coup, was waging konfrontasi, an
>   undeclared war against Singapore. The Philippines was claiming Sabah
>   in East Malaysia. Standards of living were low and economic growth
>   slow. America's action enabled non-communist Southeast Asia to put
>   their own houses in order. By 1975 (when the Vietnam war ended) they
>   were in better shape to stand up to the communists. Had there been no
>   US intervention, the will of these countries to resist them would have
>   melted and Southeast Asia would have most likely gone communist. The
>   prosperous emerging market economies of Asean ( Association of
>   Southeast Asian Nations) were nurtured during the Vietnam War years.[1](http://www.pressrun.net/weblog/2009/07/lee-kuan-yew-mcnamara-and-the-vietnam-war.html)

1. Is the belief that US military action in South East Asia gave time and space to these countries held by a significant body of scholars?  If so, what is their opinion.
2. In what ways did other US civil and military actions impact on the development of secure capitalist states in South East Asia?
3. Is there any scholarly critique of opinions such as Yew's of US involvement in South East Asia?  If so, what is the content of this critique?

Comment: This seems speculative.  I'm skeptical that an answer can be crafted in less than book length.

Comment: I don't think this is authoritatively answerable. However, it might be possible to survey scholarly opinion on this subject.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about alternate history.

Comment: Both RI Swamp Yankees answer and ComeAndGo's comment are correct. Meaning that this is a matter of opinion.

Comment: At the risk of extending a comments thread further, I want to acknowledge the effort that has gone into editing this question to make it fit.  We sometimes forget that H:SE questions are a fairly narrow set of history questions.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Seems that I can't make it fit though, so I'll vote to close.

Comment: Well, I think if forced to, I'd go with something like, "What's the general opinion amongst historical scholars on this subject? Is there one?"

Comment: Since Lee Kuan Yew is a primary source on this matter and was intimately involved with the politics of the region in question, I'm not sure why anyone would want to dispute him without **very** solid substantiation, unless they had some sort of political agenda RE the Vietnam War.

Comment: @ComeAndGo "unless they had some sort of political agenda."  What do you think the ruler of a viciously anti-communist state has regarding the American war?  The reason why we have historiography instead of just lists of primary sources is precisely due to the lack of distance in time and politics from the events in question which most primary sources possess.

Comment: @SamuelRussell - Note the source cited. It is just not a question of what he said. It's also concerning his actions at the time, because of his _in the field_ dealings with the situation. He **knew and experienced** what was going on there. **The Vietnam war helped his efforts** as an anti-communist in Singapore and vicinity. I fear you are jumping to discredit the source because of personal bias.

Comment: No, because of methodology.  Yew's direct involvement is the chief reason to doubt his capacity to provide an analysis at the standards demanded of historical analysis.  He may incidentally have the right opinion, but his argument from personal experience is a bad one.  Moreover, the place to start wouldn't be with his public pronouncements, but with Singaporean cabinet documents, in particular public order documents.  Yew has every reason to lie about the state of public order in Singapore (as would any head of state).  This is why primary sources are rarely relied upon for their analysis.

Comment: @SamuelRussell - _No, because of methodology..._ - OK, I don't necessarily agree, but I understand 'where you're coming from'. You have a point.

Comment: @SamuelRussell It is confusing to refer to Lee Kuan-Yew as *Yew*. *Yew* is not his surname. His family name is *Lee*. Calling him *Yew* would be a bit like calling Mao Tse-Tung, *Tung*. Chinese names usually consist of three monosyllables, The first is the family name and the next two the given name. Sometimes the English-speaking Overseas Chinese will adopt a western name. Lee Kuan-Yew, was mostly known to British officials as *Harry Lee*.

Comment: For a dissertation in my retirement, I researched the 1961 decision to include Singapore in the Malaysian Federation. At that time it faced a serious communist threat, exacerbated by the large numbers of immigrants arriving from Cultural-Revolution China. I discovered ample evidence that the Kennedy Administration, prior to the first Viet-Nam skirmishes, put great pressure on Britain to retain its considerable naval, ground and air commitments, including its nuclear capability, on the island of Singapore. This Britain did until 1972 despite the crippling cost.

Comment: The most important decisions re Britain granting independence to Singapore on the understanding that it be included in Malaysia were taken in the wake of the *Bay of Pigs* disaster. There were fears in western capitals about the possibility of Singapore "becoming another Cuba". Singapore was seen in London and Washington as a vital component of western geo-strategy, and Lee Kuan Yew as vital to its realisation.

Answer (score 1):

This argument only makes sense if the war in Vietnam drew away money, manpower and attention from the other regional Communist fights - in other words, did volunteer brigades from Singapore and Malaysia and the Phillipines take up the fight for North Vietnam? Did communists in those countries lend significant aid to the NVA or Viet Cong that stalled their own ambitions domestically?

No, they did not. The [Pathet Lao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathet_Lao) and [Khmer Rouge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khmer_Rouge) *did*, and their nations wound up under communist regimes. So the opposite of the author's assertion appears to be true. The United States radicalized and legitimatized communist rebels in neighboring nations through inept and callously brutal strategy, allowing them to gain and consolidate power.

As to the notion that the resources of Vietnam's larger allies - the Soviet Union and its European allies and China - were enmired in the conflict, this is dismissed by noting the successful anti-colonial revolutions in Africa occurring at the same time (Mozambique, Guinea-Bisseau, Congo, Angola, etc.) that were backed by money, men and material from the communist powers.

Comment: -1  _This argument only makes sense..._ : **IMO this is all wrong**: If the USA had not intervened in Vietnam, the emboldened and strengthened communist regime there, backed by the Chinese, could have quickly combined forces with the rest of the communist groups in SE Asia and dominated the entire region. Because the US intervened, the Viet-Cong and the Chinese were held at bay, and in other places the communists movements were left far more to their own devices and so were not successful. That's the "breathing room" Lee Kuan Yew is referring to.

Comment: I really like the first paragraph - this is a good way to rephrase a question so that it fits within H:SE.  "Can we create a hypothesis/test/thought experiment which would allow us to distinguish between potential counterfactuals?"  It isn't perfect, but it is better than I thought possible.   This may not be the perfect test, and I may or may not agree with the conclusion, but I like the approach.

Comment: @ComeAndGo - Well, then, did communist Vietnam lend men, money or material to other Communist insurrections? No. They actually engaged in a brief war with Cambodia that overthrew the Khmer Rouge. The assertion that the Viet Nam war achieved any end is speculative at best, and countered by actual rather than speculated history.

Comment: Also note the Soviet Union (and its Eastern Block allies) and China backed successful revolutions in Africa and Central America with men, money and material at the same time as the war in Vietnam - their resources were *demonstrably* not tied up exclusively in Vietnam.

Comment: This chat shows my general problem with personal opinion answers on subjects like these. Its eminently arguable. To be honest, I personally could probably argue somewhat persuasively for either side. It would be far better to survey the opinions of experts on the subject (if such a thing exists), and leave it at that.

Comment: @RISwampYankee  - Since Lee Kuan Yew is a primary source on this matter and was intimately involved with the politics of the region in question, I'm not sure why anyone would want to dispute him without very solid substantiation, unless they had some sort of political agenda RE the Vietnam War. As for your logic, none of it holds water at all IMO. But I opt for T.E.D.'s comment...

Comment: +1 It was only an anti-communist war for the US. It was primarily a war of national liberation for Vietnam. Communism was a straw man in the Domino theory - the end of colonialism caused the political unrest.

Comment: @ComeAndGo Well, obviously Lee Kuan Yew himself has a political agenda ;) So, I think his statement cannot be taken as an objective statement of fact - that's his take and his interpretation. Primary sources are great, but they have to be subjected to a source criticism exercise before use... P.S. A more immediately useful primary source would be a *Communist* leader lamenting the failure to communize South East Asian states because of Vietnam. Yew's view is rather his estimate of what went on the Communist side - he is a primary source who himself only had had partial information at the time.

Comment: -1 I am afraid. There is another way in which Yew's statement makes sense (though it may be wrong): Management is 80% about the prioritization of goals, so the Communist leadership on a worldwide scale (and there were 2 such rival leaderships by the time Vietnam was finished) too had to prioritize its goals. By putting Vietnam at the top of the list they by default prioritized the takeover of other countries lower. The present answer, alas, ignores this interpretation.

Comment: @Felix - _Well, obviously Lee Kuan Yew himself has a political agenda_ - see my comments to SamuelRussell on the question (not sure if I buy his retort...) and take a look at the link provided in the question to Lee's remarks.

Comment: @ComeAndGo I am still with Samuel on this one, especially this part: "This is why primary sources are rarely relied upon for their analysis"; that's the point I was trying to make, but pit it less cogently.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg - _I am still with Samuel on this one..._ - OK, you are entitled. ;) Regardless, I think there is a lot of agreement around here that this answer is not a very good one.

Comment: @James -  _Communism was a straw man in the Domino theory_ - Communism was no **straw man** - there were communist initiatives driven by the USSR all over the world. And post USSR there is still plenty of fuel left in the communist gas tanks, particularly in Latin America. Of course, if you're a Marxist, that's good....

Comment: @ComeAndGo There were nationalist movements around the world, some of which the USSR helped to fund, but these grew from the vacuums left by the end of colonial power as a consequence of WW2. There was no globally coordinated single communist movement linking all these nations. Each nation had its own flavour of political and economic organisation, but normally wanting to replace a corrupt despotic regime. Domino theory was about fear of losing control and justifying intervention to regain it.

Comment: @James - I don't buy it. The Bolsheviks and their heirs believed in expansionism and pursued it. I gather you're a Marxist oriented revisionist. We will not agree.

Comment: @James _communism was a straw man in the Domino theory-the end of colonialism caused the political unrest_ -non sequitur here: the political unrest does **not** make communism a straw man. Stalin  teamed with the allies partly because he understood the vacuum that would ensue when Hitler was defeated and intended to capitalize on it to expand communism however/wherever possible. Churchill knew it, Roosevelt winked... The US was not a big colonial power and they were interested in capitalizing on their victory just as Stalin was. That was the Cold War - it was not a bluff or a myth.

Comment: @comeAndGo Yes, we are unlikely to agree, but please do not make ad hominem statements. You final statement suggests even in the absence of communism, states would fall due to the power vacuum - surely that makes communism a straw man?

Comment: @James: _surely that makes communism a straw man?_ Again, non sequitur here.

Answer (score 1):

As a Filipino who has lived thru the 1970's, the US foreign policy against Communism has a deep impact in our country. Communism was used as a reason by Former Philippines President (dictator in some accounts) Ferdinand Marcos to declare Martial Law (http://www.gov.ph/featured/declaration-of-martial-law/). Also the US was very aware of the said declaration.

You might say that the US policy may not be a cause of the declaration of Martial Law, but the mere fact that Communism was the reason used by Marcos, then it should be blamed.

Regarding the effect on the country, the economy of the Philippines in 1970's suffered. (http://countrystudies.us/philippines/57.htm)